# How to get access and change style of an element with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am coding a survey. If a button is clicked the color of the clicked button is changing. I want to provide the possibility to the user to deselect a button if he for example clicked or selected respectively the wrong button. Therefore, I changed the class of the selected button to have a exclusive access only to the selected button to set the style-attributes to default when deselect the button. I tried different ways but none of them worked. Where is my failure? My code is below.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const option = document.getElementsByClassName("button");

  const forward = document.getElementById("forward");

  Array.from(option).forEach(function(option) {
    option.addEventListener("click", () => {


      option.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(77, 55, 120)";
      option.style.opacity = "0.65";
      option.style.color = "white";

      //Changong buttons backgroundcolor to purple

      let keySelector = option.querySelector(".key-selector");
      keySelector.style.color = "white";
      //determine the key-selector and turn the color into white

      forward.style.color = "white";
      forward.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(77, 55, 120)";
      forward.style.transition = "1s ease";
      //changing the color of the continue-button to purple when at least one element is selected

      option.className = "selected-button";
      console.log(option.className);

      //replace class name of selected-element to provide the possibility to have access to the selected element in order to deselect if required
    });
  });
  const selectedButton = document.getElementsByClassName("selected-button");

  Array.from(selectedButton).forEach(function(selectedButton) {
    selectedButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      //if selected element is clicked again turn the style-settings to default
      keySelector.style.color = "rgb(51, 51, 51)";
      keySelector.style.opacity = "0.6";

      selectedButton.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(226, 226, 226)";
      selectedButton.style.color = "black";
      selectedButton.style.opacity = "1";
      //return the colors when a button is deselected

      selectedButton.className = "button";
      console.log(option.className);
      //turn the class name to default to have provide the possibility to select the element again
    });
  });
};
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans Avestan', sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: rgb(77, 55, 120);
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 4rem;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 45px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.nav-text {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  width: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.instruction {
  padding-top: 8rem;
  left: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 730px;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

.options {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 313px;
  max-width: 750px;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 15rem;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 15px;
  position: sticky;
  left: 8rem;
}

.button,
.selected-button {
  background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  height: 418.75%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 21px 25px 22px 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 16.8px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.text {
  margin-left: 4rem;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(194, 194, 194);
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#backward:hover,
#forward:hover {
  background-color: rgb(77, 55, 120);
  color: white;
}

.key-selector {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.6;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}

.button:hover .key-selector {
  color: black;
}

.button-bar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.nav-inner {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 83px;
}

#backward {
  background-color: rgb(101, 93, 93);
  color: white;
}

#forward {
  background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);
}
```

```html
<div id="work-container">
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li class="section"><a class="nav-text" href="client.html">A</a></li>
    <li class="section"><a class="nav-text" href="case.html" style=" border-bottom: 1px solid;">B</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="instruction">
    <h3>Please choose an answer. You can choose more than one answers.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="options">
    <div class="option">
      <div class="button">
        <div class="key-selector">
          <span>A</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text">1</div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="option">
      <div class="button">
        <div class="key-selector">
          <span>B</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text">2</div>
      </div>


    </div>

    <div class="option">
      <div class="button">
        <div class="key-selector">
          <span>C</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text">3</div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="option">
      <div class="button">
        <div class="key-selector">
          <span>D</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text">4</div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="option">
      <div class="button">
        <div class="key-selector">
          <span>E</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text">5</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="button-bar">
    <div class="nav-inner" id="backward">
      < Back</div>
        <div class="nav-inner" id="forward"> Continue ></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You're only using the `selected-button` class when the page is loaded. So changing the class won't have any effect later.

Comment: But the event listener for selected button will not work if it is not in the window.onload

Comment: First the code then the comments.  the respectively comments stands for the code above the respectively code.

Comment: Please [edit] your title so that it makes sense. You appear to be missing some words.

Comment: @HereticMonkey my english is limited I am open for suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only looping over `selectedButtons` when the page first loads. Since there are no elements with the class at that time, nothing gets the second event listener.

Instead of two different event listeners, use a single event listener that tests the class of the element.

```
if (option.classList.contains("selected-button")) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do somthing else
}
```

It's also generally better to use the `classList` methods than assigning to `className`, so you don't remove other, unrelated classes. This would allow you to add/remove the `selected-button` class without removing `button`, so you don't need to assign the same style to both classes in CSS.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const option = document.getElementsByClassName("button");

  const forward = document.getElementById("forward");

  Array.from(option).forEach(function(option) {
    option.addEventListener("click", () => {
      let keySelector = option.querySelector(".key-selector");
      if (option.classList.contains("selected-button")) {
        let selectedButton = option;
        //if selected element is clicked again turn the style-settings to default
        keySelector.style.color = "rgb(51, 51, 51)";
        keySelector.style.opacity = "0.6";

        selectedButton.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(226, 226, 226)";
        selectedButton.style.color = "black";
        selectedButton.style.opacity = "1";
        //return the colors when a button is deselected

        selectedButton.classList.remove("selected-button");
        console.log(option.className);
        //turn the class name to default to have provide the possibility to select the element again
      } else {
        option.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(77, 55, 120)";
        option.style.opacity = "0.65";
        option.style.color = "white";

        //Changong buttons backgroundcolor to purple

        keySelector.style.color = "white";
        //determine the key-selector and turn the color into white

        forward.style.color = "white";
        forward.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(77, 55, 120)";
        forward.style.transition = "1s ease";
        //changing the color of the continue-button to purple when at least one element is selected

        option.classList.add("selected-button");
        console.log(option.className);

        //replace class name of selected-element to provide the possibility to have access to the selected element in order to deselect if required
      }
    });
  });
};
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans Avestan', sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: rgb(77, 55, 120);
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 4rem;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 45px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.nav-text {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  width: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.instruction {
  padding-top: 8rem;
  left: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 730px;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

.options {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 313px;
  max-width: 750px;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 15rem;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 15px;
  position: sticky;
  left: 8rem;
}

.button {
  background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  height: 418.75%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 21px 25px 22px 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 16.8px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.text {
  margin-left: 4rem;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(194, 194, 194);
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#backward:hover,
#forward:hover {
  background-color: rgb(77, 55, 120);
  color: white;
}

.key-selector {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.6;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}

.button:hover .key-selector {
  color: black;
}

.button-bar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.nav-inner {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 83px;
}

#backward {
  background-color: rgb(101, 93, 93);
  color: white;
}

#forward {
  background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);
}
```

```html
<div id="work-container">
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li class="section"><a class="nav-text" href="client.html">A</a></li>
    <li class="section"><a class="nav-text" href="case.html" style=" border-bottom: 1px solid;">B</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="instruction">
    <h3>Please choose an answer. You can choose more than one answers.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="options">
    <div class="option">
      <div class="button">
        <div class="key-selector">
          <span>A</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text">1</div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="option">
      <div class="button">
        <div class="key-selector">
          <span>B</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text">2</div>
      </div>


    </div>

    <div class="option">
      <div class="button">
        <div class="key-selector">
          <span>C</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text">3</div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="option">
      <div class="button">
        <div class="key-selector">
          <span>D</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text">4</div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="option">
      <div class="button">
        <div class="key-selector">
          <span>E</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text">5</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="button-bar">
    <div class="nav-inner" id="backward">
      < Back</div>
        <div class="nav-inner" id="forward"> Continue ></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: So should i remove the window.onload ? If I am doing this the eventListener will not work anymore.

Comment: window.onload should still work

Comment: So it is kind of working. But when I deselect one all other selected elements will be deselected. To solve this I replaced the Array for selectedButton with querySelector but now when I select several elements and deselect one the first button will be deselect simultaneously and than the second and so one...

Comment: Wasn't that the problem you had yesterday, and I showed you how to fix it?

Comment: No. When you select for example all buttons and deselect than the fourth button not the fourth button will be deselected but unintentionally the first than the second etc. http://jsfiddle.net/s2r3k71c

Comment: I've put the full code in my answer. I don't see it deselecting all the other elements.

Answer (score 1):

Let me tell you the mistakes in your code.

```
Array.from(option).forEach(function (option) {
```

is a very wrong way to add event listeners. Use event delegation.

```
option.className = "selected-button";
```

is a wrong way to add class. Use `classlist.add()/classlist.remove()`.

```
const selectedButton = document.getElementsByClassName("selected-button");
```

You are adding a query of `selected-button` at the time of window load. You will not get any element in this case, because classname will be added if button is selected, and will not be present at the time of load. Event delegation will save you again.

```
element.style.backgroundColor = "purple"
```

This again is a piece of text from another world. Create a CSS class, `.active` and add/remove the CSS class.

Answer (score 0):

You literally need 0 javascript for this part. CSS has the :focus and :disabled pseudoclasses, and HTML has the "disabled" attribute and automatically sets the focused element for CSS (:focus is the selected button/input):

```css
button {
  color: black;
  background: aqua;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 4px 5px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

button:disabled {
  background: silver;
  color: gray;
}

button:focus {
  background: #aaf;
  outline: 2px solid aqua;
}
```

```html
<button disabled>Disabled</button>
<button>Back</button>
<button>Next</butotn>
```

There's also the HTML form element, which can have required fields of different types:

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" placeholder="Number"><br>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password"><br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Required text" required><br>
  <input type="date"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Send"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: @fijiwa65 What in particular isn't working?

Comment: This will not work for me because you cannot focus on several elements simoultaneously

Comment: @fijiwa65 I thought you were talking about selecting elements. Do you mean selecting like a multiple choice question?

Comment: @fijiwa65 Sorry, I hadn't scrolled down far enough in your code snippet to see what you mean. You can use checkboxes and the css :checked and :not(:checked) properties to find them. Finding how many answers are checked will need some Javascript though.